# Mapbox Opacity Example Touchscreens

Tags: layers, mapbox

In Mapbox, this example works on a PC but not on a touchscreen Android/iPhone/iPad

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/opacity/

Is there a simple change to the code below to make it work on mobile devices?

==================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Opacity control</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<style>
.ui-opacity {
  background:#FFF;
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:70px;
  height:200px;
  width:28px;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius:3px;
  z-index:1000;
  }
.ui-opacity .handle {
  position:absolute;
  background:#404040;
  left:0;
  top:20px;
  width:26px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  cursor:ns-resize;
  }
  .ui-opacity .handle:hover {
    background:#303030;
    }
</style>

<div id='map'></div>
<div id='control' class='ui-opacity'>
  <div id='handle' class='handle'></div>
</div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'AAAAAAAA';
var handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
    start = false,
    startTop;

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.emerald')
    .setView([43.6654, -79.4775], 14);

var overlay = L.mapbox.tileLayer('aibram.Aerial', {
      zIndex: 2
    })
    .addTo(map);

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (!start) return;
    // Adjust control.
    handle.style.top = Math.max(-5, Math.min(195, startTop + parseInt(e.clientY, 10) - start)) + 'px';
    // Adjust opacity.
    overlay.setOpacity(1 - (handle.offsetTop / 200));
};

handle.onmousedown = function(e) {
    // Record initial positions.
    start = parseInt(e.clientY, 10);
    startTop = handle.offsetTop - 5;
    return false;
};

document.onmouseup = function(e) {
    start = null;
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, iPhone + Safari, iOS 13.3.
Most likely not possible to fix

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the example on a mobile browser (Android 4.4.4, firefox 46.0.1) and had the same problem. My guess is that it's a bug with mapbox.js and/or leaflet.